# I am trying to show rating star icon but unfortunately not showing properly in table using java script

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to show rating star icon a/c to rating number but unfortunately rating star icon is not showing properly please help me how can i show that ? a/c to rating number thanks.

please check image
https://ibb.co/1Jxd6yr

**In first row**

rating star icon should be shown 3.

**In second row**

rating star icon should be shown 4.

**In third row**

rating star icon should be shown 5.

**script**

```
function format ( d ) {
    let variantCount = d.review.length;
    let table = `<div class="custom_datatable transfer-table blue-table mt10"><table 
    class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center" width="5%">S.No</th>
                <th width="20%">Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>`;

        if(variantCount > 0){
          d.review.forEach((variantCount, index)=>{

            if(variantCount.rating == 1){
              variantCounts =  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
            }else if(variantCount.rating == 2){
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
           }else if(variantCount.rating == 3){
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
           }else if(variantCount.rating == 4){
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
           }else if(variantCount.rating == 5){
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
              variantCounts=  "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
           }else{
                  
             }

            table += `
              <tr class="no-click">
                <td>${index+1}.</td>
                <td>${variantCount.name}</td>
                <td>${variantCount.email}</td>
                <td>${variantCounts}</td>
                <td>${variantCount.description}</td>
              </tr>
            `
            })
        }else{
          table += `
             <tr class="no-click">
            <td></td>
             
             <td  colspan="3" class="text-center">There is no data available in the table</td>
            </tr> 
          `
        }
      
        table += `</tbody>
          </table></div>`;

    return table;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (variantCount.rating == 1) {
    variantCounts = "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
} else if (variantCount.rating == 2) {
    variantCounts = "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
} else if (variantCount.rating == 3) {
    variantCounts = "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
} else if (variantCount.rating == 4) {
    variantCounts = "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
} else if (variantCount.rating == 5) {
    variantCounts = "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
    variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You every time set same string to variantCounts variable.
You must use

> +=

```
like:  variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
```

You can also use for loop, instead of if

```
 for(var i = 1; i <= variantCount.rating; i++){
      variantCounts += "<i class='fa fa-star stars' aria-hidden='true'>";
    }
```